# Find the View and container Fargment information from Click event captures in profiler

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler

I am profiling a new application I am working with. I can see the captured pink circle, I want to find out where the view is ,In which fragment and where the click listener is defined.
Here I can only see the activity information.
It's a big project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version of Android Studio, when hovering over the green bar near the top, there should be a tooltip showing the Activity and Fragment.

Regarding how to find out the View, have you tried Android Studio's [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)? I don't know a single-click way to locate the listener but it may be feasible once you locate the view.